# How to use Interpolations on SharedArray in worker process without each process creating its own copy of data?

Tags: interpolation, julia, shared-memory

I'm using the Julia 0.4.6 currently in 64bit Debian Stretch ("testing").  I'm currently using it in a 4 core 4Gbyte VM.

What I'm basically trying to do is have the main process set up a 3D SharedArray, and then parallelize the production of a 2D array derived from that 3D array over worker processes.  The catch is, if I want the workers to access that volume (all of it, as I can't predict which bits they'll actually need) via an interpolation, I seem to be having problems with rampant memory usage.

Here's some minimal code demonstrating what I'm trying to do...

First an interpolation free version:

```
# Initialize 1GByte of SharedArray
volume=SharedArray(Float32,(512,512,1024))  # 1 GByte of shared data
volume[:,:,:]=rand(Float32,(512,512,1024))

# Function to compute directly from array
function test0()
  image=SharedArray(Float32,(512,512))
  @sync @parallel for y=1:512
    for x=1:512
      image[x,y]=volume[x,y,512]
    end
  end
  sdata(image)
end

println(mean(test0()))
```

That works fine whether I run it with no workers or -p 2, -p 4 , -p 8 or -p 16 (there's not a lot of performance improvement, but bear in mind this is just a model for something which does much more compute in each iteration).

However this version:

```
using Interpolations

# Function to compute via interpolator
function test1()
  sampler=interpolate(volume,BSpline(Linear()),OnGrid())

  image=SharedArray(Float32,(512,512))

  @sync @parallel for i=1:512*512
    x,y=ind2sub((512,512),i)
    image[x,y]=sampler[x,y,512]
  end
  sdata(image)
end

println(mean(test1()))
```

starts the system swapping with -p 2, and -p 4 has the workers terminating with `OutOfMemoryError`s.

What I'm *guessing* is that the serialization of the interpolator to the worker processes loses sight of the fact it's sitting on a  SharedArray, and just copies the data wholesale into a non-shared copy in each worker.

My question is: what can I do to improve this?  Is there a better pattern for what I'm trying to do here, or some cunning use of `@<something>` that'll result in each worker interpolating off the shared array instead of it's own copy?

**Update:**

This approach seems to usefully push the creation of an interpolation object into each worker processes:

```
function test(volume)

  image=SharedArray(Float32,(512,512))

  sampler=Nullable()

  @sync @parallel for i=1:512*512
    x,y=ind2sub((512,512),i)
    if isnull(sampler)
      warn(STDERR,"Allocating sampler...")
      sampler=Nullable(Interpolations.interpolate(sdata(volume),Interpolations.BSpline(Interpolations.Linear()),Interpolations.OnGrid()))
      warn(STDERR,"...allocated sampler")
    end
    image[x,y]=get(sampler)[x,y,512]
  end
  sdata(image)
end
```

...however it still suffers from exactly the same problem and with more than a few worker processes will start swapping or fail to create the samplers due to memory exhaustion.

A closer inspection of the [Interpolations.jl](https://github.com/tlycken/Interpolations.jl) code suggests it generally expects to pad and/or pre-filter the array given (which obviously means it taking a copy)... however I can't yet read Julia well enough to understand whether `BSpline(Linear())` has any chance of bypassing those copies being made and avoiding the massive per-process memory overhead.  I see the Quadratic interpolation offers the intriguing option of prefiltering being done "InPlace" but I haven't explored this further yet (a significant issue would seem to be avoiding *all* the workers attempting to prefilter the shared data).

Comment: My gut instinct here is that you'd be better of with `remotecall()`, `@spawn` or the like.  I've found that `@parallel` can be a bit sketchy at times in terms of how it handles data movement, and thus some of the other parallel features in Julia that give you more direct control over what is going on can be better.  I'll see about taking a look later today or tomorrow if you and/or someone else hasn't worked it out before then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apparently](https://github.com/tlycken/Interpolations.jl/issues/114) the solution is to use the `interpolate!` version of interpolate.  This works great with as many worker processes as I throw at it:

```
using Interpolations

# Function to compute via interpolator
function test(volume)

  image=SharedArray(Float32,(512,512))

  sampler=interpolate!(
    volume,
    Interpolations.BSpline(Interpolations.Linear()),
    Interpolations.OnGrid()
  )

  @sync @parallel for i=1:512*512
    x,y=ind2sub((512,512),i)
    image[x,y]=sampler[x,y,512]
  end
  sdata(image)
end

# Initialize 1GByte of SharedArray
volume=SharedArray(Float32,(512,512,1024))  # 1 GByte of shared data
volume[:,:,:]=rand(Float32,(512,512,1024))

println(mean(test(volume)))
```

There's also a `prefilter!` which hints it may be possible to use the higher order interpolation methods similarly too, but linear interpolation is good enough for my purposes.

Comment: Super, I'm so glad to hear there's a resolution to this!